# Antique headboard and footbard with iron frame

Tags: antique

I have an antique headboard and footboard along with the one piece iron frame that attaches to it.  Problem is that when you attach the frame to the head and footboards, the "L" shape is upside down so there's no way to use slats or to secure the mattress in the bed. I can't turn the frame upside down because the holes in the frame and the bed wouldn't align properly (there's also a small nodule on the frame that fits into the head and footboards).  Any help/suggestions/advice will be greatly appreciated. I used this bed in a former home but that was over 30 years ago and I just can't remember how it was set up!

Comment: A photo would help us see what is going on.  But suspect maybe it is designed for a box spring set.

Comment: Turn the head- and foot- boards upside down :-) .   But really-- there's no reason to believe the "L" - shape is intended to capture the mattress or boxspring.  Setting the frame in the upside down  (Greek Gamma) config is mechanically much stronger for supporting a load.  And, yeah, a box spring would obviate the need for slats.

Comment: Actually, we came up with a fix over the weekend and it's working beautifully!  We added screw inserts into the holes and then just used screws to hold the head and footboards on . . . works like a charm!  And the box spring and mattress fit perfectly on the bed frame.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the rails swapped. Right on left and upside down. Try moving them to the opposite side and turned top to bottom I think you will find they fit that way and hold the slats in place.

Comment: The frame is actually riveted together; no way to take apart.  BUT we did come up with a fix and it's working beautifully!  Thanks!